# Роутинг в ExtJS 6 - как грамотно раскидать роуты по viewcontroller

Tags: маршрутизация, extjs, router

коллеги!

С недавних пор занимаюсь разработкой проекта на ExtJS 6.2, в ближайшем будущем планируется переход на 6.6. Мучает меня одна проблема - роутинг.

Сейчас в контроллере главного представления веду обработку текущего значения хеша в адресной строке, определяю какое дочернее представление нужно подгрузить исходя из параметров в хеше, добавляю в главный view нужное представление и viewcontroller,  затем выполняю redirectTo() на роут дочернего контроллера, где уже и происходит вызов нужных методов.

Это решение меня не устраивает, так как возникает много глюков с повторным переходом к форме - когда пользователь перешел на другую форму, а затем вернулся на предыдущую (вознкают задвоение вызова методов API, наблюдаются неактуальность данных, несвоевременный вызов методов роутера, глюки при использовании force:true в redirectTo).

Подскажите наиболее тривиальное и правильное решение, как вести обработку и вызов нужных методов и работе с роутером при доступе к формам приложения с большим множеством дочерних для mainView ViewController'ов. 
Вероятно, есть более тривиальные решения именно в 6.5+, основанных на миксинах, но качественных примеров использования Ext.route.Mixin тоже найти не могу.

Благодарен за любые комментарии на основе ваших опытов и за примеры реализации задачи.

Comment: Ну хоть кто-нибудь!)